# Dynamically get information from Databags -Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I'm using chef-version [Chef: 10.14.4]. I would like to create several recipes, that read and write dynamic information to and from a databag about different services running on different servers.

Here's an example:

1. I'm running an apache service on server1, server2 and server3.
2. Now, in one of my recipe for server1, I would like to start/execute a web service, but before doing that I need to make sure server1, server2 and server3 are running apache service.

Questions are:

- How do I design a recipe for apache service to dynamically update the databag?
- How do I design the web service recipe to get the dynamically updated information from the databag?

Or, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use databags to let one server to know about the other. Use [search](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Search). You can search the nodes by attributes, recipes, tags and so on. In your case you can search for nodes that have your apache service in run list. If you get all 3 nodes as a result of search, then hopefully they have apache running.

If you still want/need to update databags from your recipe, see **Creating and Editing Data Bags within a Recipe** in [Data Bags help](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Data+Bags).

Comment: Thnx for the reply.How do I get all the three nodes and the status of the apache services running on them using search ? Can you please give me an example ?

Comment: You can't get the status of apache service, but if you have a recipe that starts apache service you can assume the the nodes that have it in [extended] run list have apache running.